# Can Yocto create more than one module from a single recipe?

Tags: linux-device-driver, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to create a set of linux driver modules under yocto. The drivers are fundamentally very similar but for reasons of hardware, have a separate source file for each interface resulting in a set of N modules. All of the drivers share functionality which is contained in set of separate files.
What I would like is that all the module source files and the set of shared files share a directory (or the latter are in a subdirectory) and that the yocto recipe generates a module from each driver source resulting in N separate modules from the one recipe.
Is this feasible or can anyone suggest an alternative that does not require replication of the shared files for each module?

Comment: Is it not part of Linux kernel? Are they even kernel drivers?